# Where are header files for GCC located?

Tags: gcc, c, compiler

I want to manually add some header files like `math.h` and `graphic.h` for `gcc` but don't know where to put them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First take a look in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`.

If you find nothing there, try :

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
```

This command asks gcc which C++ preprocessor it is using, and then asks that preprocessor where it looks for includes.

You will get a reliable answer for your specific setup.

Likewise, for the C preprocessor:

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

Answer (score 9):

To look for header locations just use the **locate** command:

```
locate -b '\math.h'
locate -b '\graphics.h'
```

or a simpler approach

```
locate \*/math.h
locate \*/graphics.h
```

If you are more familiar with regular expression use

```
locate -r \/math.h$
```

To make sure the database is up-to-date start:

```
sudo updatedb
```

That's the way I'm searching my headers location. It's much faster than using the *find* command.

#### Finding headers in not installed packages

For sake of completeness I post a one liner script which is in my mind very useful in finding apt packages involving a special header file.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
apt-file search $1 | cut -f 1 -d ":" | sort -u
```

Save this one liner for instance in your `~/.local/bin` directory as e.g. `aptfilesearch` and make it executable with `chmod +x aptfilesearch`. Now you get a list of all packages including the header file you are searching for. Here a simple demonstration:

```bash
aptfilesarch math.h
```

Comment: `math.h` should already be present. Example : `/usr/include/c++/7.3.0/math.h`

Comment: How does the backslash act to prevent matching by files with preceding characters in their basename?  The string `\math.h` should evaluate to `math.h`, but I see that `\math.h` avoids matching files like `tgmath.h` and `quadmath.h`.

Comment: FROM 'man locate' :  To search for a file named exactly NAME (not \*NAME\*), use
              locate -b '\NAME'
       Because \ is a globbing character, this disables the implicit replacement of NAME by \*NAME\*.

Comment: Thanks. I had checked `man locate`, but I guess I have a different version of the `locate(1)` man page (which doesn't have one instance of `\ `).

Comment: ```info locate``` or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html